# Handling late MQTT messages

Tags: python, timestamp, mqtt, iot

I'm making a Python program that sends and receives data using MQTT. The sending device is often portable and might not have a reliable connection, so it's very much possible for messages to arrive late.

For the program to function correctly, the messages need to arrive in a somewhat timely fashion, say 20 seconds or so. If the messages arrive later than that then some special handling needs to happen.

My problem is determining if a message is late or not, and if so by how much. The first thing that comes to my mind is for the publisher to add a timestamp to the message that the subscriber can then check, but that depends on the publisher and subscriber having a synchronized clock. There is no guarantee that all of the users of this program will have accurate system times. There also isn't necessarily a guarantee of having admin access to correct the system time.

Another thought was to use ntplib or something like that to apply a timestamp from an NTP server at the moment of publishing, but this also depends on having a reliable internet connection, which is the problem I'm trying to solve in the first place.

Is there another way to get synchronized time between publisher and subscriber? Another way to determine how late a message is that I'm not thinking of?

### UPDATE

My thought was to get a time offset from an NTP server on connect, then apply that offset to the timestamps generated from time.time(). For example:

```py
import ntplib

time_offset = 0
ntp_client = ntplib.NTPClient()

def update_time_offset():
    global time_offset
    try:
        resp = ntp_client.request('pool.ntp.org')
        time_offset = resp.offset
        logger.info(f"Time offset set to {time_offset}.")
        return True
    except:
        logger.warn("Unable to update time offset.")
        return update_time_offset()


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):   
    t = Thread(target=update_time_offset)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

The publish function:

```py
    def publish(message):
        now = time.time()
        timestamp = now + time_offset
        payload = json.dumps({"message": message, "timestamp": timestamp})
        mqtt_client.publish("topic_name", payload, qos=1)
        print("Published to MQTT.")
```

And the subscribe function:

```py
    def _new_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        payload = json.loads(message.payload.decode())
        now_corrected = time.time() + time_offset
        message_transit_time = round(now_corrected - payload["timestamp"], 1)
        message_data = payload["message"]
        stripped_message = " ".join(message_data.split())
        print(f"Message {stripped_message} transit time: {message_transit_time}.")
```

This should have worked in theory, but I ran into the following problem: some users run the program on boot on devices like raspberry pi. A raspberry pi doesn't have a hardware clock, so the system time is incorrect at boot until updated by ntpd. My program was getting a time offset before the system time was updated, resulting in wildly incorrect transit times. I think for now, rather than add more complexity to my code, I will trust that the users system times are relatively accurate and see how I do.

Answer (score 1):

No

If you have a requirement of knowing if a message takes longer than 20 seconds to be delivered, then you have no choice than to have all devices have access to matching time sources.

The only way to mark the message creation time is to include a timestamp in the message it's self, and this can only be checked against the receiving device's current time.

You could just publish the current time as a retained message on a given topic that way everything has a roughly shared source of time. If done at QOS 0 it wouldn't be queued so shouldn't arrive late

Comment: If you have no chance to use NTP, microseconds aren't that important and the connection has sometimes a quite low latency and sometimes a high one: Publish the timestamp in the MQTT Broker and get the message frequently combined with a ping to determine the latency and use the systemclock to generate an own timestamp in your remote app. You could use the signal quality, ping time or anything else to determine if your latest time-sync with mqtt was reliable or not. Then send the message with that timestamp. Anyway: still a quite hacky solution..

Comment: Here's an idea: in the on_connect callback function get the current time from an NTP server. Since we just connected to the broker it seems safe enough to assume we have a good connection at the moment. Subtract the system time from this time to get a time delta. Then, when publishing a message, apply a timestamp that is the system time minus the time delta. This should keep everything in sync?

Comment: So, wouldn't I have to continuously publish the current time for this solution to work? And wouldn't that involve setting one device as the master clock? Or am I not grasping it completely?

Comment: Yes you would. But as I've said already if you care about late delivery you **MUST** synchronise clocks at some point. Of course you could just run ntpd on what ever you nominate to be the master clock